# Magento 2. Make product page as first page

Tags: magento2

How to make a specific product page as homepage (first page) in Magento 2.1.11?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the default web url in

> store > configuration > general > web > default pages

to be the url you want.

Comment: Glad i could help.